John 1:1, "the Word was with God, and the Word was God." Vs2, He was in the beginning with God. Does this not prove Jesus existed before Genesis 1:1?
Genesis 1:1, "In the beginning God created the heavens and the earth." The "beginning" here is referring to when time began "God created the heavens and the earth."
How else are you going to explain John 1:3, "All things came into being by Him, and apart (or without Him) nothing came into being that has come into being."
And if you think about it, the Genesis 1:1 beginning describes "WHAT HAPPENED" in the beginning. The John 1:1 beginning, explains WHO EXISTED in the beginning BEFORE anything was created. In fact, one could say that the beginning at John 1:1 antecedes the Genesis 1:1 beginning. (Some of this was taken from the (Institute of Creation Research).

@MrBond. Assuming God is The Father, the son and the holy spirit and the word is the son, can we say then that in the beginning was the son, and the son was the Father, the son and the holy spirit and the son was the Father, the son and the holy spirit?

@Alex Balilo I'm not waisting my time  with "lame" assumption questions. And I'm be generous using the word "lame."

@MrBond. Trying to find out who the God the word was with is lame?

The doctrine of the holy trinity is true and I am glad to have accepted it. The term us God used in his statement to create man shows that God is a term of beings, three beings who make up God

@SoFewAgainstSoMany says "The doctrine of the holy trinity is true" — That is irrelevant on this site. The question is about John 1:1–18, at most, and that scripture doesn't even mention "spirit". ¶ "The term us God used in his statement to create man shows that God is … three beings" — Again, one could interpret "we" as referring to more than one being, but there is no indication that it means exactly three.

'Jesus' is the name applied (by Gabriel) to the baby born in Bethlehem. 'Logos' is an aspect of Deity. And the  mystery is that 'Logos was with God in the beginning' and 'God was the Logos'. There is a mystery in Deity, as such. Then there is another mystery - 'God manifest in flesh'. Up-voted +1, but I do wish you would deal with these two mysteries separately.

@RayButterworth, its related to trinitarianism, I do know you are a binitarian who believes that the only two beings that make up God include The Father and the Son, the Holy Spirit is also an independent being who is part of the Holy Trinity because Jesus mentioned the Father, The Son and The Holy Spirit when he was talking about the unforgivable sin.

@RayButterworth, Jesus compared the three beings because they all make up the us that God referred to before creating man.

+1 And let me add that "beginning" is a Time word, part of the initial Genesis creation of space-time and matter. From this, obviously, it makes zero sense to ask any spatial, temporal, and material questions concerning creation when it didn't exist. Furthermore, many people struggle with the concept that God doesn't need to exist within his creation. And finally, whatever God creates is of necessity less complex than God. This part of the nature of the nature of information. Thus, God is way more complex than the human immune system, quantum mechanics, and Euler-Lagrange equations.

@SoFewAgainstSoMany I'm glad that you consider the Biblical teaching of the Trinity to being true. Having said that the following of what you said here is not true. "The term us God used in his statement to create man shows that God is a term of beings, three beings who make up God." No, the Trinity is made of three distinct persons, not three beings. The definition of "being" is the state or quality of having existence. Person is defined as "All the qualities constituting one that exists. the essence, one's basic or essential nature, personality. Three beings is like saying three gods.

@Mr.Bond, you cannot be a person without being a being. a being is an intelligent person such a s man or a spirit

@SoFewAgainstSoMany - you are forcing God to abide by human limitations (where "being" and "person" are 1-to-1)

The "Logos" is a technical title for Jesus is clear from John 1:1, 14, 1 John 1:1, Rev 19:13.
Now, one of the things that John 1:3 says that ALL things were either created or came into being by Jesus, then I believe it.  This is the same teaching as in John 1;10, Col 1:16, 17, Heb 1:2, 10.
Further, it is an elementary piece of logic and set-theory that says that if Jesus was the means by which all things came into existence, then Jesus cannot Himself be created!
Thus, if Jesus was the originator of all things, then Jesus must have been the originator as recorded in Gen 1.

'Logos' is a title applied to Deity as such. Manifestation is not in view. It is not 'a title for Jesus'. 'Jesus' is the name applied (by Gabriel, who stands in the presence of God) to a baby born in Bethlehem.

@Nigel J, While our speech results merely in creating compression waves in air, God spoke space-time and matter into existence. His words manifested as the reality that we experience. God's Logos and Pneuma were intimately involved in manifesting our reality and are themselves both manifestations and personifications of God. In that sense, God's Love and God's Wisdom could also be considered such personifications. As such, they are more than qualities, names, and titles in the same way that a cube is more than a square.

@Dieter 'are themselves both manifestations' Absolutely not.

Kindly consider the following: 8 Anyone who does not love does not know God, because God is love. 9 In this the love of God was made manifest among us, that God sent his only Son into the world, so that we might live through him.  - 1 John 4:8,9 ESV

Regarding an "elementary piece of logic and set-theory", you might be entertained by the fact that logicians and set theorists certainly do study systems which deny the axiom of regularity.

@LeeMosher - yes - that is a well-known axiom.  Many thanks for the reminder.

Answer
Definitely John 1:1 does prove Jesus existed eternally and hence much before Genesis 1:1
Explanation
Not only John 1:1, other verses also prove that Jesus existed eternally with no beginning:
Yahweh claims:

“I YHWH am the first and the last; I am He” (Isaiah 41:4).


“Listen to Me, O Jacob, and Israel My called: I am He; I am the
First; surely I am the Last” (Isaiah 48:12).

Does it mean that Yahweh is created?
Not at all!
Yahweh also claims,

“And I will not give My glory to another” (Isaiah 48:11).

Jesus claims:
Yet, we see Jesus claiming for Himself the same glory!

“These things says the First and the Last, Who became dead,
and lived” (Rev 2:8).


“Do not fear. I am the First and the Last, and the Living One; and
I became dead; and, behold, I am living forever and ever. Amen”
(Rev 1:17-18).

Does it mean that Jesus is created?
Not at all!
Same terms apply both ways
Just as God the Father is Creator and yet “the Beginning and the Ending” (Rev 1:8; 21:6), Jesus is Creator and yet “the Beginning and the Ending” (Rev 22:13).
Just as Yahweh God is Creator and yet “the First and the Last” (Isaiah 41:4; 48:12), Jesus is Creator and yet “the First and the Last” (Rev 1:17-18; 2:8).
In other words, if God the Father can be "the Beginning (Arche)" without the sense of being created, then Jesus definitely also can be "the Beginning (Arche)" without the sense of being the first created!
If Yahweh God can be "the First (Protos)" without the sense of being created, then Jesus definitely also can be "the First (Protos)" without the sense of being the first created!
Conclusion
Lord Jesus Christ is the eternal and great God just as His Father God is eternal and great. So John 1:1 precedes Genesis 1:1 quite well.

+1 Excellent! Many people overlook what "the beginning" actually means in context of Genesis 1.

Thank you for the upvote and your good words, Dieter.

In John's opening chapter of his gospel, the name of Jesus does not appear until verse 17.
Yet from verse 1 to verse 14 the One who is "the Word" is mentioned four times.
It is not until after the Word was made flesh (verse 14) that John and all the others who had been with Jesus could understand that the Word had become flesh in the person of Jesus Christ. Therefore, John wrote in his first epistle:

"That which was from the beginning, which we have heard, which we have
seen with our eyes, which we have looked upon, and our hands have
handled, of the Word of life; (For the life was manifested, and we
have seen it, and bear witness, and shew unto you that eternal life,
which was with the Father, and was manifested unto us;) That which we
have seen and heard declare we unto you, that ye also may have
fellowship with us;: and truly our fellowship is with the Father and
with his Son Jesus Christ.
"For this purpose the Son of God was manifested, that he might destroy
the works of the devil." 1 John 1:1-3 & 3:8 A.V.

Put that together with John 1:1-18 and a clear order appears. First, the eternal Word of God who is also the eternal Son of God, who (at a specific point in time) became flesh as the baby conceived in the virgin Mary's womb.
For the sake of clarity and precision, it is appropriate to refer to the eternal Word and the eternal Son as one and the same, prior to that point in time. Thereafter, there is a human person called Jesus of Nazareth. He turns out to have had the glory of his preincarnate state veiled while he walked on Earth as a man (the only exception being at the transfiguration, when three of his disciples got a glimpse of that).
But the human Jesus did not exist until the Holy Spirit overshadowed Mary, using her human nature to enable the divine nature of the Word, the Son, to become flesh. By all means speak of the Word existing before creation started; by all means speak of the Son existing before creation started, but (technically) no-one can say the man, Jesus existed before creation started. Yet Christians understand what is meant when that is said; it is being said with hindsight, having grasped the connection between the Word, the Son, and the man, Jesus. Yet it remains back-to-front to imply that the man, Jesus, existed before creation began. To be biblically precise, we ought to stick to saying the Word, the Son, existed before creation
Yes, "John 1:1 explains WHO EXISTED in the beginning BEFORE anything was created." But John is careful never to mention the name of Jesus until after the Word became flesh. Should Christians not take the same care?

+1 In this regard, I believe that the full nature of God can be revealed and experienced, though never fully understood. Thus, one should be advised to stick closely with the revealed titles and self-descriptions of Jesus: the Son of Man, the Son of God, Messiah, the Lamb of God, the Bread of Life, and so on. Otherwise, we're virtually certain to be wrong, which is exactly the case with the Gnostics.

I cover that first sentence in this recent answer to this Q: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/102930/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-biblical-term-divine-nature-and-what-does-it-tell/102933#102933

@Dieter I forgot to put that at the start of my comment above, so you may not have seen it yet.

Thank you, yes, I did see your comment and I read your linked post twice. Interestingly, there are four references to "seven spirits of God" in Revelation and the last reference in Revelation 5:6 indicates they belong to the Lamb, along with his seven horns. I don't have any idea how the seven spirits of God relate to the Holy Spirit nor do I understand why Jesus would have seven horns, but I do know that I should tread carefully.


All things were made through him, and without him was not any thing made that was made.
(John 1:3, ESV)


πάντα διʼ αὐτοῦ ἐγένετο, καὶ χωρὶς αὐτοῦ ἐγένετο ⸂οὐδὲ ἕν⸃˸. ὃ γέγονεν˸
(John 1:3, NA28)

Literally: All things [everything] became through him and without him not one thing became.
Where ὃ γέγονεν belongs is another question not relevant to this one.
Thus, not only does this say that ὁ λόγος (the Word) was present in Genesis 1:1, but the Word did not become but is eternal.
John 1:14 clearly refers to Christ:

And the Word became flesh and dwelt among us, and we have seen his glory, glory as of the only Son from the Father, full of grace and truth.
(John 1:14, ESV)


Καὶ ὁ λόγος σὰρξ ἐγένετο καὶ ἐσκήνωσεν [an old Greek word similar to the Hebrew word used for God dwelling in Exodus; see TDNT] ἐν ἡμῖν, καὶ ἐθεασάμεθα τὴν δόξαν αὐτοῦ, δόξαν ὡς μονογενοῦς παρὰ πατρός, πλήρης χάριτος καὶ ἀληθείας.
(John 1:14, NA28)


+1 Clearly articulated and supported. I'm also reminded of Hebrews 1:3: "He is the radiance of the glory of God and the exact imprint of his nature, and he upholds the universe by the word of his power. After making purification for sins, he sat down at the right hand of the Majesty on high."

There is a lot more to this answer than meets the eye.  Stay with me as we delve into the dynamics of this passage, because there is a ton to digest.
So overly fixated on translation, we often fail to recognize how underlying Jewish traditions, themes, and OT allusions can (and should) impact the way we translate, understand, and interpret the text.
Most commentators acknowledge that John’s prologue is an allusion to Gen. 1, but don’t give much recognition to other intertextually related passages, which are otherwise quite commonly weaved together (intertextually) in Jewish sources.  Consider,
4 Ezra 6:1-6, 38

And he said to me, “At the beginning of the circle of the earth,
before the portals of the world were in place, and before the
assembled winds blew, [2] and before the rumblings of thunder sounded,
and before the flashes of lightning shone, and before the foundations
of paradise were laid, [3] and before the beautiful flowers were seen,
and before the powers of movement were established, and before the
innumerable hosts of angels were gathered together, [4] and before the
heights of the air were lifted up, and before the measures of the
firmaments were named, and before the footstool of Zion was
established, [5] and before the present years were reckoned; and
before the imaginations of those who now sin were estranged, and
before those who stored up treasures of faith were sealed -- [6] then
I planned these things, and they were made through me and not through
another, just as the end shall come through me and not through
another.” … [38] I said, “O Lord, thou didst speak at the beginning of
creation, and didst say on the first day, ‘Let heaven and earth be
made,’ and thy word accomplished the work.”

In the ensuing narrative, the author elaborates on God’s creation project (cf. 4 Ezra 6:36-55).  The point of citing this portion of the narrative (4 Ezra 6:1-6, 38) is because it emphasizes a point which Isaiah 45 stresses: That God alone is responsible for creation, without the assistance of other gods (Isaiah 45:14-18 LXX).  4 Ezra 6 weaves together themes from Gen. 1 and Isaiah 45.  Here, the scribe of 4 Ezra 6 identifies the “gods” of Isaiah 45 as the “host of angels.”  In the 4 Ezra account, the “host of angels” did not exist prior to Gen. 1:1, but came into existence at some point during the 7-day creation project.  That this is the point being elucidated, is made clear by what it stated in 4 Ezra 6:3, 6: That “before the beautiful flowers were seen, and before the powers of movement were established, and before the innumerable hosts of angels were gathered together,” God “planned these things, and they were made through me and not through another, just as the end shall come through me and not through another.”
4 Ezra 6:4 (“they were made through me and not through another”) over emphasizes the point made earlier in 4 Ezra 6:3 (“before the innumerable hosts of angels were gathered together”): That no angel was present with God prior to Gen. 1.  Still, according to 4 Ezra 6:38, God spoke at “the beginning of creation” through His “word.”  4 Ezra does not consider this “word” to be an angel or a secondary god, but lumps the existence of the celestial hosts into the Genesis story of creation with all the rest of created order, of which God made through this “word.”
Likewise, Jubilees 2:1-10 also lumps the existence of the heavenly celestial armies into the Genesis story of creation.  This does not necessarily mean that John was relying on 4 Ezra or Jubilees 2, but it does provide insights into how pre-Christian or contemporaneous
Jews perceived “creation.”  The point of mentioning 4 Ezra, isn’t so much to highlight the existence of the heavenly court into Genesis (though, important), but rather: That undergirding 4 Ezra 6:4 lies texts like Isaiah 45:14-18 LXX, and Deut. 32:39 LXX.
Isaiah 45:14-18 LXX pits the one God of Israel against other “gods” by way of contrast:

“Thus says the Lord, who made heaven—this is the God who displayed the
earth and made it; he himself marked its limits; he did not make it to
be empty but to be inhabited: I am, and there is no other.”

What distinguishes this one God from all other “gods” is the act of creation, something that the “word” participates in.
In the context from which John draws from (Isaiah 45), lies an example of how John could have written Jn. 1:1 had he intended an indefinite rendering (Isaiah 45:11-18 LXX cf. Deut 4:35 LXX, Deut. 32). Had John intended to mean that the Word was “a god,” then he probably would have done so the way Isaiah 45 stresses indefiniteness. Had he followed the verbal patterns of Isaiah 45, it “definitely” (pun intended) would have been more emphatic, and laid stress on the fact that there was “a god” with God prior to the formation of the universe. The allusion being drawn upon needs to guide our interpretation and translation in the same way it governed and encapsulated John’s thought when he penned Jn. 1:1; after all, we have to assume he’s not trying to contradict the very place he alludes. John is not trying to expand on some “all new” concept about the λόγος, but is in keeping with the OT’s reflections on λόγος (cf. Jer. 1:4-9, 32:26-27). John just gives us a little bit of his own Christological ponderings and reflections in light of an era so saturated in λόγος speculation. It’s John’s way of expressing his own Christological convictions and reflections (“from the margins,” so-to-speak), in keeping with his own Jewish heritage. John is “riding on the curtails” of Isaiah 45, Genesis 1, all the meanwhile, incorporating his very own personal “style/touch” to the text to demonstrate that Christ was there, using language (πρὸς τὸν θεόν) exclusively used elsewhere to illustrate the relationship between God the Father and Christ (cf. Jn. 1:1b, 13:1, 13:3, 14:6, 14:12, 16:5, 16:10, 16:17, 16:28) without also contradicting the very place governing his line of thought (Isaiah 45).
Envision a playwright: Who in the narrative is playing the lead roles? In John's narrative, Christ wears the “hat” of “the Word,” through whom God made the world (Gen. 1:1, “And God said…”).  Yet, in the OT (cf. Jer. 1:4-9, 32:26), the λόγος is nowhere depicted as a “second god,” but the force and power — God's own words — through which He used to create (Ps. 33:6). It is in this light that John places Christ right into the paradigm.  John uses anthropomorphic language to describe Christ so as not to compromise monotheism.
In light of these connections and associations, one ought not understand John as identifying Christ as an external force (or a “second god”) through whom God used to create the universe, but within God’s very own “metaphysic” itself: As God’s own Word.
When Jn. 1:1 speaks of the Word existing “with” God, the term used here for “with” is the Greek word πρὸς.  When followed by a noun in the accusative case, πρὸς speaks of face-to-face communion, interaction. One does not need to leave the first chapter of John to find examples in which πρὸς signifies a person near or moving towards another person (e.g., 1:29, 42, 47).
There are (14) instances in the Gospel of John alone, where some slight variation of the phrase πρὸς τὸν θεόν (Jn. 1:1b) is used.  The number swells to (17) if we also include John’s Epistles.  And if the Apocalypse is included, it swells to a whopping (19) occurrences.  Included in these tallies are,

This language (with some slight variation), is elsewhere used throughout the Testaments — including Acts 4:24, 12:5, 24:16; Romans 5:1, 10:1, 15:30; 2 Cor. 3:4, 13:7; Philippians 4:6; 1 Thess. 1:8, 9) — and another 20+ examples in the Genesis and Exodus accounts of the Greek OT  (Gen. 17:18, 18:27, 18:31, 20:17, 24:49, 24:54, 24:46; Exodus 2:23, 3:11, 3:13, 8:25, 8:26, 9:29, 10:18, 18:19, 19:8, 19:21, 19:23, 19:24, 24:1, 24:2, 32:30). In each of these occurrences (aside from the occurrences where the neuter article τὰ is present), they explicitly refer to distinct individuals in some form of communication with one another.
In each instance (aside from the few that are often disputed, i.e., Jn. 1:1, 1:2, and likely 1 Jn. 1:2) there is real personal and numerical distinction.  This is standard Johannine rhetoric when speaking of Christ’s decent/ascent to the heavenly places.  Take Jn. 13:1-12 (Lexham) as an example,

Now before the feast of Passover, Jesus, knowing that his hour had
come that he would depart from this world to the Father (πρὸς τὸν
πατέρα), and having loved his own in the world, loved them to the end.
And as a dinner was taking place, when the devil had already put
into the heart of Judas son of Simon Iscariot that he should betray
him, because he knew that the Father had given him all things into
his hands, and that he had come forth from God and was going away to
God (πρὸς τὸν θεόν), he got up from the dinner and took off his
outer clothing, and taking a towel, tied it around himself. Then he
poured water into the washbasin and began to wash the feet of the
disciples, and to wipe them dry with the towel which he had tied
around himself. Then he came to Simon Peter. He said to him, “Lord,
are you going to wash my feet?” Jesus answered and said to him,
“What I am doing you do not understand now, but you will understand
after these things.” Peter said to him, “You will never wash my feet
forever!” Jesus replied to him, “Unless I wash you, you do not have a
share with me.” Simon Peter said to him, “Lord, not my feet only,
but also my hands and my head!” Jesus said to him, “The one who has
bathed only needs to wash his feet, but is completely clean. And you
are clean, but not all of you.” (For he knew the one who would
betray him; because of this he said, “Not all of you are clean.”)
So when he had washed their feet and taken his outer clothing and
reclined at table again, he said to them, “Do you understand what I
have done for you?”

Within the span of just a few short sentences, John uses such language (twice) in the immediate context to speak of Christ’s departing “to” God (and seven more times as the narrative progresses).  But the reason for citing this example in Jn. 13 is not only to show the frequency in which John uses the language, but also the surrounding context in which it is used.  There are conceptual similarities in Jn. 13 to the earlier Pauline work to the Philippians.
In Jn. 13, (and pay attention to the details of this) “knowing (εἰδὼς) He had come forth from God and was going away to God (πρὸς τὸν θεόν),” Christ rises from the table and lays aside His “outer garments,” clothing Himself with a towel (v. 4).  In Phil. 2, Christ divests Himself of His glorious garments (vv. 6-7) by clothing Himself with human nature (cf. 2 Cor. 8:9).
In Phil. 2, Christ takes the form of a slave, yet, in Jn. 13, He performs a menial task often assigned to slaves (washing the feet of others).
In Jn. 13, upon completion of this task, Christ once again takes up His (former) outer garments.  In Phil. 2, after His work on earth is finished, He returns to the visible glory with the Father that was His before time.
In Phil. 2, Christ is exalted by the Father and sits down (once more) on His heavenly throne, yet, in Jn. 13, Christ resumes His place at the table, from which He had temporarily departed.
The story in Jn. 13 is an example of humble service. In Phil. 2, Paul uses the incarnation and humiliation of Christ as an example of humble service (Phil. 2:1-5).
With the imagery and conceptual ties to Phil. 2 in the backdrop, John seizes upon language from his prologue (πρὸς τὸν θεόν) and weaves it back into the narrative to demonstrate that Christ will once more “resume His place at the table,” from which He had once departed (Jn. 1:1).  He was “with” God in the beginning (Jn. 1:1, Phil. 2:6), and was now going back to God (Jn. 13:3-4, Phil. 2:9-11), seated at the right hand of God.
But even more striking are that the words recorded in Jn. 13:3-4 are not the “spoken words” of Christ (or of the narrator for that matter), but even as the narrator explains, are the “inner-thinkings” (εἰδὼς) of Christ, which seems to form yet another connection to Phil. 2:6 in that both texts place Christ’s thoughts and contemplations on “equality with God,” which again points us back to the prologue, Jn. 1:1.  Fresh on Christ’s mind was: πρὸς τὸν θεόν (Jn. 1:1, 13:3-4), which He then goes on to elaborate/reflect on (or, “speak His mind”) in the ensuing narrative (specifically, Chapters 14 through 17):

But I tell you the truth, it is better for you that I go away. For
if I do not go away, the Advocate will not come to you; but if I go, I
will send him to you. And when he comes, he will convict the world
concerning sin and concerning righteousness and concerning judgment:
concerning sin, because they do not believe in me, and concerning
righteousness, because I am going away to the Father (πρὸς τὸν πατέρα)
and you will see me no more, and concerning judgment, because the
ruler of this world has been condemned. I still have many things to
say to you, but you are not able to bear them now. But when he—the
Spirit of truth—comes, he will guide you into all the truth. For he
will not speak from himself, but whatever he hears he will speak, and
he will proclaim to you the things to come. He will glorify me,
because he will take from what is mine and will proclaim it to you.
Everything that the Father has is mine. For this reason I said that he
takes from what is mine and will proclaim it to you. “A little
while and you will see me no more, and again a little while and you
will see me. So some of his disciples said to one another, “What is
this that he is saying to us, ‘A little while and you will not see me,
and again a little while and you will see me,’ and ‘Because I am going
away to the Father (πρὸς τὸν πατέρα)’?” So they kept on saying,
“What is this that he is saying, ‘A little while’? We do not
understand what he is speaking about!”  Jesus knew that they were
wanting to ask him, and he said to them, “Are you deliberating with
one another about this—that I said, ‘A little while, and you will not
see me, and again a little while and you will see me’? Truly, truly
I say to you, that you will weep and lament, but the world will
rejoice; you will become sorrowful, but your sorrow will change to
joy. A woman, when she gives birth, experiences pain because her
hour has come. But when her child is born, she no longer remembers the
affliction, on account of the joy that a human being has been born
into the world. So you also are experiencing sorrow now, but I will
see you again, and your hearts will rejoice, and no one will take away
your joy from you. And on that day you will ask me nothing. Truly,
truly I say to you, whatever you ask the Father in my name, he will
give you. Until now you have asked nothing in my name. Ask and you
will receive, so that your joy may be complete.  “I have said these
things to you in figurative sayings. An hour is coming when I will
speak to you in figurative sayings no longer, but I will tell you
plainly about the Father. On that day you will ask in my name, and
I do not say to you that I will ask the Father on your behalf. For
the Father himself loves you, because you have loved me and have
believed that I came from God. I have gone out from the Father and
have come into the world; again, I am leaving the world and am going
to the Father (πρὸς τὸν πατέρα).” His disciples said, “Behold, now
you are speaking plainly and are telling us no figurative saying!
Now we know that you know everything and do not need for anyone to ask
you questions. By this we believe that you have come from God.”
Jesus replied to them, “Now do you believe? Behold, an hour is
coming—and has come—that you will be scattered each one to his own
home, and you will leave me alone. And I am not alone, because the
Father is with me. I have said these things to you so that in me
you may have peace. In the world you have affliction, but have
courage! I have conquered the world.” Jesus said these things, and
lifting up his eyes to heaven he said, “Father, the hour has come!
Glorify your Son, in order that your Son may glorify you— just as
you have given him authority over all flesh, in order that he would
give eternal life to them—everyone whom you have given him. Now this
is eternal life: that they know you, the only true God, and Jesus
Christ, whom you have sent. I have glorified you on earth by
completing the work that you have given me to do. And now, Father,
you glorify me at your side with the glory that I had at your side
before the world existed.” (Jn. 16:7-17:5)

I will conclude by ending with a couple rejoinders:
The term “Word” in and of itself portrays a sense of agency.  To be called God's “Word” is to say they are God's “mouth.”  That they are God's “mediating agent,” which is otherwise expressed in Jn. 1:3 (agent of creation).  Thus, the term, “Word” implies (or expresses) what is already explicit in Jn. 1:3 (the notion of agency).  The titular, “the Word” overshadows Christ's role as God's mediating agent.  Thus, the qualitative θεὸς in 1:1c also accounts for this idea of agency (or mediation): That this figure dubbed “the Word” is none other than God's agent which mediates God's very nature and being.  That He is the one that mediates light to man.  The qualitative θεὸς underscores Christ's role as God's mediating agent.
And just to add a brief word to what Perry Webb has pointed out about the Word being eternal: The prologue of John's gospel shares certain verbal affinities with the epistle of 1 John.  In Jn. 1:1, the form of the word “was” (ἦν), is a timeless word. It signifies continuous or linear existence in the time period specified, “In the beginning” (John 1:1a). John 1:1a speaks of continuous existence during a specified time period (“In the beginning”); therefore, it does not follow that we are also talking about coming into existence during that same period.  Picking up on this, John develops this further in the epistle of 1 John 1:1-2 by way of intertextual “pun.”  In the gospel account, the Word exists with God eternally.  But 1 John redevelops this idea through the lens of “eternal life.”  1 John 1:1-2 is a “midrash” on John 1:1.

+1 for research and for saying, "That this figure dubbed 'the Word' is none other than God's agent which mediates God's very nature and being."  I like that.  That which God expresses would mediate to others exactly who he is. Otherwise, there would be something foreign (and not true) introduced into the expression. The author of Hebrews states it this way: "the exact representation of His nature."

+1 as well for research. For those of you, who don't know, 4 Ezra is considered an apocryphal text. Here's a sympathetic description from an Orthodox perspective: https://blogs.ancientfaith.com/wholecounsel/2018/09/26/4-ezra-a-biblical-book-youve-probably-never-read/

Let us substitute the terms "Word" and "God" based on the notion that the Word is the Son. and the "God" is the Father, the Son and the Holy Spirit.
In the beginning was the Son, and the Son was with the Father, the Son and the Holy Spirit, and the son was the Father, the Son and the Holy Spirit. We need to delineate and define words so we can better understand.
If one thinks that God is divisible, then an explanation as to who is the God that the "Word" was with needs to be identified as the statement "the Word was with God" is right before the statement "and the Word was God".  There is no record of a God the Word creating in the bible. That the Word is God and was also the God it was with is a contradiction.
John 1 is not speaking of the Genesis creation. It is a contrast between Jesus and John the Baptist. See John 1:2 and John 1:7. Notice that John 1:8 says that John was not the light when it is obvious that the light existed long before John the Baptist came into existence.
Comparing John 1:3 with Genesis 1:1. we find that John 1:3 does not have the word create or make. That is why others translate "egeneto" as "happened". The word "egeneto" in the New Testament does not carry the meaning to create or make out of nothing. The word "things" was also not in this verse originally. In addition, the word "all" in the gospel of John was never used to mean all creation.
If "God" and "logos" are not defined, then some ideas postulated by liberally giving these words meaning other than what they really mean, ideas that are contradictory to what the rest of the bible say may be given a semblance of truth, but, when examined, are inconsistent to be considered true and biblical.

This does not even address the question.  Please answer the question.

@Dottard. The question is a question based on an assumption. Syllogisms that are not proven factual. So I addressed that and the question. You can judge my answer however you want.

So, does that mean you either cannot or will not answer the question?

@Dottard. You are asking if I am going to answer when I already did. You have freedom to judge my answer however you see it, I have already answered the question.  Does the verses used clear as to who is the God that the word was with? Just concentrating on the word was God already answers the question? Does the verses cited only have your preferred interpretation and conclusion, and when it doesn't you judge it as not answering the question? If you have a different answer why don't you put it up?

@AlexBalilo, do you think John 1:1c says, "and the Word was himself a god"? I think so, as do others. No article before the second use of theos.

When Jesus was sent to the earth was He simultaneously in heaven? Please read Isaiah 55:10-11. When the Word of God is sent it returns after accomplishing the purpose. An analysis which attempts to understand the dynamic as yours is contrary to what God says of the Word.

@RevelationLad. Isaiah 55:10-11 says Jesus was sent to earth and was simultaneously in heaven?

Short Answer: Jesus did not exist before Genesis 1:1, but was the firstborn spiritual son of God in Genesis 1:3 as God's first work.

The opening of John 1:1 (In the beginning was the Word...") describes the origin of the Word of God who is Jesus Christ the firstborn Son of God and Angel of angels. Notice that it does not say, "For eternity was the Word," but "In the beginning was the Word."
Jesus is the firstborn of all created beings (Col 1:15), which makes him the beginning of the creation of God (Rev 3:14) as the first of God's works (Prov 8:22) which was begotten on Day 1 of the Genesis creation week (Psa 2:7, Gen 1:3) as the Light of the world (Jn 8:12, 2 Cor 4:6) who proceeded from the Father of lights (spiritual sons) who is the eternal Light.
Jesus is not the uncreated eternal God, but the created firstborn Son of God (Matt 16:15-16, 1 Cor 8:6, Eph 4:4-6). Jesus is the Chief Angel of God's Presence (Mal 3:1-2, Job 33:23, Gal 4:14) and the mediator between God the Father and man (1 Tim 2:5).

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
